# How to use php in html form?

Tags: php, html

This is a simple Captcha form which is working well and prints the requested result after I press `‘submit’`.

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
$msgCaptcha = "";
?>

<?php
   if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
      $secCode = isset($_POST['secCode']) ? strtolower($_POST['secCode']) : "";
      if ($secCode == $_SESSION['securityCode']) {
         $msgCaptcha = "valid code";
         $result = true;
      }
      else {
         $msgCaptcha = "wrong security code";
         $result = false;
      }
   }
?>      

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
name:<input name="myname" type="text"><br />
Security code: <input class="text" name="secCode" type="text">
                <img src="securityCode.php" /><br />
                <?php echo $msgCaptcha ?>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

. i.e.

If my input is the same as like in the picture the printing is “valid security code”
and if the input is not the same, the printing is “wrong security code”.

When I change in the form the code to `action="mailer.php"` this file is opened but ignore of any input in the Captcha  validation.

I need `mailer.php` to be open after Captcha validation.

I have tried `onsubmit` and some other options, but none of them works as a solution for the above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens on mailer.php (specifically with `myname`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `header()`

```
if ($secCode == $_SESSION['securityCode']) {
     $msgCaptcha = "valid code";
     header("Location: http://www.website.com/ ... /mailer.php");
  }
```

Comment: Chances are that mailer.php processes the form using `$_POST` variables.  If you redirect via header to that page, none of the form variables will carry over.

Comment: I suppose a better answer from anyone could be determined if we knew what mailer.php did.

Comment: Thank you for this simple solution but this is indirect access to my file mailer.php, and I which want to avoid.

Comment: mailer.php sends a confirmation sent email to the registered user which had submitted the form.

Comment: In this case, you should recognize that the PHP in `mailer.php` is what is important. Take the code that sends the mail and put it in the if statement that confirms the CAPTCHA was added correctly. Then, header redirect to a confirmation page that doesn't actually run any code/queries, but instead confirms that they were added to the mailer list. Anyone who visits the page manually will find that nothing actually happens.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to `include` mailer.php after the `$msgCaptcha = "valid code";` line.

Any code inside mailer.php would be executed in that block of code, and any `$_POST` variables required by mailer.php would be available.

The bottom line is, when you call mailer.php, you must have captcha validation in front of that file, otherwise any bot/spammer can bypass your captcha protection just by submitting the form directly to mailer.php

Keep in mind, bots generally ignore javascript, so the validation has to be done server side.

You may want to set a variable prior to including mailer.php that it will check so even if someone did try to directly submit to mailer.php, it won't process the form unless the file was included.

If this doesn't help, post the code for mailer.php so we know what the contents of that file are.

Comment: mailer.php start with if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
and then sends a confirmation sent email to the registered user which had submitted the form

Comment: You should just be able to include it after you confirmed that the captcha was correct.  To prevent people from accessing it directly, do something like `define('MAILER_INCLUDED', 1);` in the script where you include mailer.php from, then in mailer.php, put `if (!defined('MAILER_INCLUDED')) exit;` at the beginning of mailer.php so it can't be called directly.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, ‘drew010’ I’m using your tip in my code.